# Filtering while using the aggregating function in Julia DatraFrames: can we?

Tags: dataframe, julia, dataframes.jl

is there a way I can use 'combine' and filter inside the aggregate function?

Let's think about the domain of the fields

field1= ["A","B","C"]

field2=["X","Y"]

field=Float or Int

want any aggregation of X and Y By [A,B,C]. I have to get 3 rows and 3 columns.

in SQL is relatively easy:

Select

field1,

sum(case when field2='X' then field3 end)  SumWhenX,

sum(case when field2='Y' then field3 end)  SumWhenY

from DF

group by field1

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question you ask in the post, *yes*, you can filter rows within `combine` operations, but the operation you are describing in SQL is more concisely described as an `unstack` operation in DataFrames.jl.

### `groupby` and `combine`

To exactly replicate what your SQL code *says*, you can combine [`groupby`](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/lib/functions/#DataFrames.groupby) and [`combine`](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/lib/functions/#DataFrames.combine) with two functions that select rows using `:field2` within the `combine` operation, like this:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(
           field1 = rand(["A", "B", "C"], 10),
           field2 = rand(["X", "Y"], 10),
           field3 = rand(0:9, 10),
       )
10×3 DataFrame
 Row │ field1  field2  field3 
     │ String  String  Int64  
─────┼────────────────────────
   1 │ C       Y            8
   2 │ A       X            8
   3 │ A       X            0
   4 │ C       Y            2
   5 │ B       Y            9
   6 │ A       Y            0
   7 │ C       Y            3
   8 │ C       Y            7
   9 │ C       Y            4
  10 │ C       X            4

julia> combine(
           groupby(df, :field1), # ... group by field1
           [:field2, :field3] => ((f2, f3) -> sum(f3[f2 .== "X"])) => :SumWhenX, # sum(case when field2='X' then field3 end) SumWhenX
           [:field2, :field3] => ((f2, f3) -> sum(f3[f2 .== "Y"])) => :SumWhenY, # sum(case when field2='Y' then field3 end) SumWhenY
       )
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ field1  SumWhenX  SumWhenY 
     │ String  Int64     Int64    
─────┼────────────────────────────
   1 │ C              4        24
   2 │ A              8         0
   3 │ B              0         9
```

The filtering in these functions just use [`BitVector`s to index the elements](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#man-supported-index-types) of `:field3` where `:field2` takes certain values.

You can also return multiple columns from the same `combine` operation and either name them with a `Vector` of `Symbols`, or expand a `NamedTuple` with the `AsTable` object, so you can write this as a single `combine` function:

```
julia> combine(
           groupby(df, :field1),
           [:field2, :field3] => ((f2, f3) -> (SumWhenX = sum(f3[f2 .== "X"]), SumWhenY = sum(f3[f2 .== "Y"]))) => AsTable,
       )
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ field1  SumWhenX  SumWhenY 
     │ String  Int64     Int64    
─────┼────────────────────────────
   1 │ C              4        24
   2 │ A              8         0
   3 │ B              0         9
```

### `unstack`

The operation you describe is a long-to-wide operation, which some tabular data programs call "pivot," but DataFrames.jl calls [`unstack`](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/lib/functions/#DataFrames.unstack). The row identifiers are in `:field1`, the column identifiers are in `:field2`, and the values you want to combine with the `sum` function are in `:field3`, so the call is:

```
julia> unstack(
           df,
           :field1,
           :field2,
           :field3,
           combine=sum,
       )
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ field1  Y       X       
     │ String  Int64?  Int64?  
─────┼─────────────────────────
   1 │ C           24        4
   2 │ A            0        8
   3 │ B            9  missing
```

You'll note two differences from the combine version:

1. `:field1`-`:field2` combinations that are missing in the data are filled with `missing` in the `unstack` operation. If you want to give those combinations some other value, use the `fill` keyword argument.
2. The returned column names are the values of `:field2`. If you want to change the names of the columns, either do it afterward, or use the `renamecols` keyword argument.

Using these two keyword arguments gives:

```
julia> unstack(
           df,
           :field1,
           :field2,
           :field3,
           combine=sum,
           fill=0,
           renamecols=(x -> "SumWhen" * x),
       )
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ field1  SumWhenY  SumWhenX 
     │ String  Int64     Int64    
─────┼────────────────────────────
   1 │ C             24         4
   2 │ A              0         8
   3 │ B              9         0
```

Comment: Thank you. The "unstack" version is very elegant, and now I understand unstack is conceptually the way to go.